# What VS2010 setup project supports Windows 2000?

Tags: .net-2.0, windows-installer, windows-2000

The msi file created by the VS2010 setup/install project does not install on Windows 2000.  One will see a message like: "the procedure entry point GetNativeSystemInfo was not found"  I can use a VS2008 setup project to solve this.  What VS2010 solution is there to this problem?

Comment: There probably isn't one. Win2K is no longer a supported OS version (XP is the oldest still supported), and most software isn't designed to worry about unsupported operating system versions. You may have to use a third-party installer instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Went with InstallShield LE which is integrated into VS and is free.

Answer (score 1):

[Advanced Installer](http://www.advancedinstaller.com) can create a setup working on Win2K, it has a free version too.